# Status Bar not updating PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, statusbar, pysimplegui

I'm building a simple GUI to try to gain some familiarity with PySimpleGUI. I started by working on a geocoder, and everything else in the GUI works **except** for a single message in a Status Bar element. This element should show 'Geocoding, please wait...' (or similar string) before running the geocoding function, but this doesn't occur.

The relevant code snippet is below:

```
def makelayout():
 import PySimpleGUI as sg
 import pandas as pd 
 import threading
 sg.theme("Reddit")

 layout = [
    [sg.T("")],
    [sg.Text("Choose a file: ",size=(28,1)),sg.Input(enable_events=True,key="-INPUT-",size=(40,1)),sg.FileBrowse(pad=(5,0),file_types=(("XLSX",".xlsx"),))],
    [sg.Text("Choose the column to be geocoded: ",size=(28,1)),sg.Combo(enable_events=True,values=[],key="-HEADER-",size=(40,1))],
    [sg.Text("Choose an output location & name: ",size=(28,1)),sg.Input(size=(40,1)),sg.FileSaveAs(pad=(5,0),size=(15,1),key="-OUT-",file_types=(("CSV",".csv"),))],
    [sg.Button("Submit",size=(12,1)),sg.Checkbox("Remove duplicates?",default=False,key="-CHECK-")],
    [sg.StatusBar("",size=(100,1),key="-STAT-")]]

   while True:
    event,values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "Exit":
        break

    elif event == "-INPUT-":
        header_list = getheaders(values["-INPUT-"])
        window["-HEADER-"].update(values=header_list)

    elif event == "Submit":
        try:
            if values['-CHECK-']:
                df = pd.read_excel(values["-INPUT-"])
                df = df.drop_duplicates()
            else:
                df = pd.read_excel(values["-INPUT-"])

            if values['-HEADER-'] != '' and values['-OUT-'] != '':
                print("Header & Output are not empty") #This prints out w/o an issue.
                window['-STAT-'].update("Geocoding, please wait...") #Not showing. Why?
                id1 = threading.Thread(target=search,args=(df[values['-HEADER-']],str(values['-OUT-'])))
                search(df[values['-HEADER-']],str(values['-OUT-']))
                
                if not id1.is_alive():
                        window['-STAT-'].update("Finished geocoding! Please check {}".format(values['-OUT-']))
        except:
            window['-STAT-'].update('Error. Invalid and/or missing inputs detected.')
```

Oddly enough, the other updates to the status bar (in the except clause for instance) work without an issue. Any ideas what i'm missing?

Comment: GUI only updated when the execution back to window.read. Call window.refresh() after it if you need the gui updated immediately.

Comment: "Any ideas what I'm missing?"  -  yes, Jason has the right answer above.... call `window.refresh()` after calling `update`.  The PySimpleGUI documentation's call reference for Window.refresh - Use this call when you want something to appear in your Window immediately (as soon as this function is called). Without this call your changes to a Window will not be visible to the user until the next Read call.